# How UNIX_TIMESTAMP works

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, unix-timestamp

I'm very desapointed :-(

Why this request works fine

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE("08:00:00","%H:%i:%s"));
```

and why this other one faile ?

```
SET @date = STR_TO_DATE("08:00:00","%H:%i:%s");
select @date as _date, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@date) as _unixtimestamp;
```

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.60, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using
> readline 6.3

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a string that has a time portion only to `str_to_date()`, so the database needs to choose which datatype it should return.

I suspect that the variable assignment yields a `TIME`, which is not a valid input for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. This can be seen when looking at the result of your sedonc statement, where `@date` is in time format:

```
_date    | _unixtimestamp
:------- | -------------:
08:00:00 |              0
```

On the other hand, the direct conversion within the function (as in your first statement) probably gives enough context to MySQL so it understands you want a `DATETIME` (the date part defaults to the current date).

The problem goes away if you are explicit about the target datatype:

```
set @date = cast(str_to_date('08:00:00', '%H:%i:%s') as datetime);
select @date as _date, unix_timestamp(@date) as _unixtimestamp;
```

Yields:

```
_date               | _unixtimestamp
:------------------ | -------------:
2020-12-09 08:00:00 |     1607500800
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2e441889241d56984045831c8d2a6b01)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Finaly I used a concat like this :
`select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d "), STR_TO_DATE("08:00:00","%H:%i:%s")));`